# Custom color is not overriding the color theme

Tags: flutter, dart, themes

in my flutter app I have this dialog:

```
AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            title: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context)!.addRefusal),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: pens.map((pen) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: TextField(
                      controller: pensControllerMap[pen],
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 13.5, 14, 13.5),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Color(0xfff7f8f8),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                        ),
                        labelStyle: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Color(0xffa3a3a3),
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                        labelText: pen.name,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  LargeElevatedButtonBlue(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.cancel),
                  LargeElevatedButtonGreen(
                      onPressed: () {
                        DateTime now = DateTime.now();
                        String formattedDate =
                            DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
                                .format(now);
                        List<RefusalModel> refusals = [];
                        for (var pen in pens) {
                          double? qtyRefused =
                              double.tryParse(pensControllerMap[pen]!.text);
                          if (qtyRefused != null) {
                            RefusalModel refusal = RefusalModel((b) => b
                              ..dateTime = formattedDate
                              ..penId = pen.penId
                              ..qtyRefused = qtyRefused);
                            refusals.add(refusal);
                          }
                        }

                        BuiltList<RefusalModel> builtRefusals =
                            BuiltList<RefusalModel>.from(refusals);

                        postRefusal(builtRefusals);

                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      title: AppLocalizations.of(context)!.save),
                ],
              )
            ],
          );
```

I set the background of the Dialog white and the TextFields with a light grey background (0xfff7f8f8). when I render it the result is always the one in the picture. these two colors and not applied.

what can be the reason?

[image]

I am using a custom theme:

```
ThemeData myTheme = ThemeData(
  cardColor: cardColor,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,

  useMaterial3: true,
  primaryColor: primaryColor,
  floatingActionButtonTheme: FloatingActionButtonThemeData(
    backgroundColor: accentColor,
  ),
  elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(accentColor))),
  iconTheme: IconThemeData(
    color: iconColor,
  ),
  textTheme: _textTheme,
);
```

but I dont think this has anything to do